# tikz positioning of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to generate a simple organigram with reasonable-looking distances in x and y direction. How can I get equidistant distances between the nodes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[topline/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red,xshift=3cm, yshift=2.5cm, minimum width=15mm,minimum height=10mm},
botline/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=orange,xshift=3cm, yshift=2cm, minimum width=15mm,minimum height=10mm},
]
\node at (0,0) [topline] {A};
\node at (1,0) [topline] {B};
\node at (2,0) [topline] {C};
\node at (0,-1) [botline] {D};
\node at (0,-2) [botline] {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz node positioning]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using different `minimum width` and `minimum height`.  Set them both to the same value and you should get the distances correct.

If you add the line

```
\tikzset{x=15mm,y=15mm}
```

before beginning the picture, you'll get a nicer result.  Also make sure that your `xshift` and `yshift` are the same and you'll get something like

[image]

Finally, since a lot of your `style`s are duplicated, I separate out the duplication.

Here is the code for the last image

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    x=15mm,y=15mm,
    mybox/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,minimum width=15mm, minimum height=15mm},
    topline/.style={mybox,fill=red},
    botline/.style={mybox,fill=orange},
]
\node at (0,0) [topline] {A};
\node at (1,0) [topline] {B};
\node at (2,0) [topline] {C};
\node at (0,-1) [botline] {D};
\node at (0,-2) [botline] {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `x=15mm,y=15mm` should be included in option of `tikzpicture` environment.